# WPF 3.5 + visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I read on MSDN that it is indeed possible to create and edit WPF version 3.5 Forms/Controls with Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone have some experience with this configuration?

**Other side of the question (i'm sure many would consider this too):**

Probably I can use the new productivity/convenience features of VS 2010 with WPF 3.5.
But does it worth the effort upgrading to .net 4 merely because of the WPF 4 new features/apis?

Does wpf 4 contain major improvements that cannot be worked around (e.g. shader support or similar) or just minor ones? Also consider that I would like to use it for "classic" UI development not for creating complex 2D/3D graphics. However mentioning the latter cannot hurt either :)

Comment: What are you upgrading, VS or .net?

Comment: Made some edits. I first want to upgrade VS then maybe .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Develop WPF 3.5 applications inside VS 2010 is very common, so not sure what you want to learn by posting this question.

Of course you lose all new things introduced in WPF 4, as you should not those things implemented in .NET 3.5.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx

Some of them may be ported back to WPF 3.5, such as visual state manager,

http://blogs.windowsclient.net/wpf35sp1content/archive/2008/10/28/wpf-toolkit-visual-state-manager-overview.aspx

But you should not expect all of them can be ported.